# Using SqlBulkCopy to insert rows to a table having column of type 'xml' in SQL Server 2008 raises exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I have simple table in SQL Server with two columns `Id (BIGINT), PublishData (XML)`.

I am interested in using `SqlBulkCopy` but when I try to so using `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable)`, it gives me below exception. I am using `SqlXml` data type in C# when I create datatable and add column for `PublishData`. I think it mismatches with column type `xml` in SQL Server. I need to know what is the correct datatype I need to use while creating the datatable for `xml` column and then use it with `SqlBulkCopy`.

Any help would be appreciated?

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is
>   not valid.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.WriteBulkCopyValue(Object value,
>   SqlMetaDa taPriv metadata, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternal()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServer(Int32
>   columnCount )
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table,
>   DataRowSt ate rowState)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table)

Answer (score 0):

> need to know what is the correct datatype I need to use while creating the datatable for xml 
>   column and then use it with SqlBulkCopy

What about tying it out instead of asking here? I mean, seriously, how many data types ARE there?

I would suggest you try a STRING in .NET ;) Kind of obvious, isn't it - you can hardly store XML in a Bool or Integer data type, so the ONLY alternative to SqlXml I can see would be string.